# Xamarin forms bluetooth state change event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms application I want to handle some functionality while bluetooth state change state. Is there any event which will fire when bluetooth is on/off. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Forms doesn't have the capacity built-in so you will need to use a 3rd party package or create your own native handlers for each platform and use dependency injection to access it from forms. Some good links to get you started are

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15794/ble-bluetooth-low-energy-cross-platform-support

And this is an open source project with example code on interacting with Bluetooh on 2 platforms. Bluetooth and BLE are different with WP8 not supporting BLE but I believe UWP does, though thats only in preview.

https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/master/Source/Platform%20Stacks